# Fuel SDK - Ruby Client - Delete a row from a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, ruby

I'm using the FuelSDK, ruby version. The retrieve rows function worked fine for me, but the function to remove a row from a data extension gives me an error.

This is what I'm doing:

```
client = ET_Client.new auth
de_row = ET_DataExtension::Row.new()
de_row.authStub = client
de_row.CustomerKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
de_row.props = {"Web_FIC" => fic}
response = de_row.delete
```

And this is the error that I receive:

**TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
from /Users/raphaelpetegrosso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/fuelsdk-0.1.7/lib/fuelsdk/objects.rb:220:in `[]='
from /Users/raphaelpetegrosso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/fuelsdk-0.1.7/lib/fuelsdk/objects.rb:220:in`block in add_customer_key'
from /Users/raphaelpetegrosso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/fuelsdk-0.1.7/lib/fuelsdk/objects.rb:218:in `each'
from /Users/raphaelpetegrosso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/fuelsdk-0.1.7/lib/fuelsdk/objects.rb:218:in`add_customer_key'
from /Users/raphaelpetegrosso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/fuelsdk-0.1.7/lib/fuelsdk/objects.rb:212:in `delete'
from (irb):37
from /Users/raphaelpetegrosso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in`start'
from /Users/raphaelpetegrosso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/raphaelpetegrosso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in`'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in`'**

I'm using ruby 1.9.3.
Any idea why I'm having this problem?

---

UPDATE

I opened your gem and checked that the error was in this line:

```
d['CustomerKey'] = customer_key
```

but in my case d is an array and not a hash. Then I changed the code to this:

```
d << 'CustomerKey'
d << customer_key
```

And it worked, but my response came with this error:

```
status_message=>"Exception occurred during [Delete] ErrorID: 1913074240"
```

It seems that the gem version is not updated, right? Any idea what is the error?

---

UPDATE 2

I solved the problem.

Comparing the request generated on the PHP version with the one of the ruby version I noticed that the PHP version had the following tags:

```
PHP Version
-----------
<ns1:Keys>
  <ns1:Key>
    <ns1:Name>Web_FIC</ns1:Name>
    <ns1:Value>XXXXXXXX</ns1:Value>
  </ns1:Key>
</ns1:Keys>
```

While the ruby version was using Properties instead of Keys and Property instead of Key:

```
Ruby Version
-----------
<tns:Properties>
  <tns:Property>
    <tns:Name>Web_FIC</tns:Name>
    <tns:Value>XXXXXXXX</tns:Value>
  </tns:Property>
</tns:Properties>
```

I changed the fuelsdk gem to use Keys and Key and it worked. I'm not sure if there is a way to set the keys without needing to change the gem, but anyway the documentation doesn't specify that.

If somebody knows a better way to set the keys (instead of properties) please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Typical issues end up being the Savon version. Are you on 2.2.0?

Comment: Post this as the answer.  Would you also add that to the repo?